# Modify ng-model from view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m pretty newbie on AngularJS, how can I update the value of my ng-model from my view? 
Right now I have form and I´m updating app_key input, but when I call my module and I check the $scope.variable, the value has not change.

Here my code

```
  <div>
    <br>
    <div class="field_row">
        <label for="app_key">AppKey:</label>
        <input id="app_key" type="text" ng-model="appKey"> --> this is the input that I´m changing the value
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="selectUser()">
    Select
   </button>
</div>
```

And in my module I have the method selectUser

```
  $scope.selectUser = function () {
        $scope.setAppKey($scope.appKey); --> Here the appKey it´s not modified
};
```

**Solution**

I dont know why, but to make it works I need to pass the ng-model to the controller function

```
  <input id="app_key" type="text" ng-model="appKey" ng-change="changeAppKey(appKey)">
```

Comment: Where you define your controller in `html`?

Comment: yes it´s defined previously on the html

Comment: Do you get any error on browser console?

Comment: nope, not errors at all, I can see that $scope.appKey is just not updated with the new values added in the input

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(this.appKey)` inside controller function?

Comment: @paul, definitely, angular update that model value. can u share your workable solution on plnkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: My only question is if I have to do something special to modify a ng-model in my input. Or I just can asume that if my input in the view just add a new value the ng-model --> $scope.appKey will be updated automatically

Comment: @paul: The `$scope.appKey` is automatically updated indeed. Check out my answer.

Comment: We need more code, that show there you define `ng-controller` and `ng-app`.

Comment: @paul [*fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/572/) is it what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/24350/) using your code. It seems to work just fine. Are you sure your `setAppKey` function is correct ?

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selectUser = function () {
        console.log($scope.appKey);
    };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>
        <div class="field_row">
            <label for="app_key">AppKey:</label>
            <input id="app_key" type="text" ng-model="appKey">
        </div>
    </div>
    {{appKey}}
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="selectUser()">
        Select
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It´s working indeed, I dont know why not on my app. But thanks a lot!, I will use this code as a base to compare